# New Ubuntu 20.04.2 update broke my PC

Tags: 20.04, updates, crash

I am having a very serious issue. I just updated to the latest Ubuntu version (the old one was Ubuntu 20.04.1 and the new one is 20.04.2), and I didn't restart my PC. I started a video clip and noticed that the display looked awful, like big pixels everywhere. I decided to restart my PC and now after the Ubuntu logo on boot it looks like in the picture below.

Please, anyone, know how to help me?

[image: Screen corruption]

Comment: Boot from an older kernel at GRUB, and see if that restores your video.

Comment: I think I tried this. I spammed ESC while booting and the GRUB menu appeared and I selected older version. Now I am installing new Linux, alongside the old one to see if it's going to work. Could be a hardware problem not sure